# Problem in adding jar library in JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

How to add a folder that contain jar files in jni c++. for example i have a folder "MyLib" that contains "Math.jar","Stats.jar" and "Temp.jar". I want to add "MyLib" to classpath insted of adding all the jar files like

**options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\myjni\MyLib";**

***instead of***

**options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\myjni\MyLib\Math.jar ; c:\myjni\MyLib\Stats.jar ; \c:\myjni\MyLib\Temp.jar" ;**

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant do that. You are allowed only to add JAR files or directories with class files to the classpath.

You could extract all jars to a directory and add this directory to the classpath.

Actully there IS a trick. Java from version 6.0 by Sun adds a possibility to expand globs. This should work in Java 6+:

```
java -cp lib/*.jar
```

So you could try this:

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\myjni\MyLib\*.jar";
```

I am not sure if it works with -D classpath setting. If you can provide the classpath cia -cp option do that. Please note the expansion is in the JVM has some limitations:

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/jdk-6-supports-in-classpath-but-be.html